# Angular 2 Final port :4200 not working with ip (192.168.0.xxx:4200) only localhost:4200 ,

Tags: angular, webpack-dev-server, ng2-admin

I am having ng2-admin template ,and not able to access from other system in same network

Comment: You sure this isn't a networking issue?  Do you have a firewall or something blocking the traffic over 4200?

Comment: nope i have seen all possibilities but still not able to resolve .